# How to combine multiple rows into one (cannot find in other threads)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, combine

Here is my dilemma;
I need to combine the same names into one row how do I do this?
I usually drag up the data into one cell and then delete the empty rows but that is very time consuming.

I am using Excel 2016

I also read another thread to press F5 and delete blank cells but it distorts the  data.

I have about 350 rows. hope this is enough info
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please [edit] your question to include details of what you have attempted so far or researched. Also, added what version of Excel you are using because it may affect the answer(s) you receive.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the data you have to the data model in excel. Then you can pivot it and do a SUM on the hours. Depending on your version of Excel, you may need to install PowerPivot add in.

Comment: I have excel 2016 how do I add the data to the data model.. sorry I'm a bit of a newbie/.

Comment: Ok I was able to add the data to a model, now just trying to figure out how to sort